# 'Can't find variable: clicks' in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, object, ecmascript-6

The following code shows an error when clicked on the 'Click Me!' button saying that the variable 'clicks' cannot be found whereas it is properly mentioned in the state

```
import { StyleSheet, Alert, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'native-base';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicks: 0
    };
  }
buttonPressed = () => {
 if(this.state.clicks > 5)
 {
    Alert.alert('Caution!','You have clicked 5 times already!');
    this.setState({clicks: 0});
    this.forceUpdate();
 }
 this.setState({clicks: clicks+1});
}
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.buttonPressed()}}>
           <Text>Click Me!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
)};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a variable name `clicks`, you should define it or use `this.state.clicks`

change this

```
this.setState({ clicks: clicks + 1 });
```

to this

```
this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 });
```

Or to this

```
buttonPressed = () => {
 let {clicks} = this.state   // define `clicks` here
 if(clicks > 5)
 {
    Alert.alert('Caution!','You have clicked 5 times already!');
    this.setState({clicks: 0});
    this.forceUpdate();
 }
 this.setState({clicks: clicks+1});
 //                     ^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`clicks` isn't a variable - it's a property of `this.state`.

```
this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line: `this.setState({clicks: clicks+1});`
The `clicks` on the right hand side of the colon is not defined.

What you can do is use the `prevState` from the `setState` function:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({clicks: prevState.clicks + 1}));
```

Comment: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/react-docs-now-recommends-using-function-with-prevstate-inside-of-setstate